# TYPO3 RealUrl - alias_field has no effect

Tags: typo3, realurl

I have a TYPO3 Installation where RealUrl is installed. It's configured and works fine for tt_news. I copied the tt_news configuration in realurl_conf.php and used it for my own extension. The configuration looks like is this:

```
'product'    => array(
    array(
        'GETvar'      => 'tx_extension_pi1[id]',
        'lookUpTable' => array(
            'table'                 => 'tx_extension_product',
            'id_field'              => 'uid',
            'alias_field'           => 'title',
            'addWhereClause'        => ' AND NOT deleted',
            'useUniqueCache'        => 1,
            'useUniqueCache_conf'   => array(
                'strtolower'     => 1,
                'spaceCharacter' => '-',
            ),
            'languageGetVar'        => 'L',
            'languageExceptionUids' => '',
            'languageField'         => 'sys_language_uid',
            'transOrigPointerField' => 'l18n_parent',
        ),
    ),

),
```

Now what I would expect is a URL like this (for tt_news this works fine):

```
http://www.mydomain.com/product/product_title.html
```

But what I get is this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/product/1.html
```

So basically the 'alias_field' parameter has no effect whatsoever, the url is always generetad with the uid of the entry. Does anyone have an idea what could cause this?

Answer: Beware of the T3 language fields. I copied the tt_news entry, but my kickstarter extension uses l10n_parent, not l18n_parent!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few guesses:

- tx_extension_product.sys_language_uid and tx_extension_product.l18n_parent, tx_extension_product.title exists?
- if you are german title or titel?
- check for PHP errors / warnings in the logfiles
- Modul Info - check Realurl configuration / Cache etc.

for me, your config looks correct.

Comment: +1 for the suggestions. The configuration looks good to me as well.

Comment: You found it! Thnx a million times, because of your comment I checked all fields again, and guess what: The language field is called l10n_parent. tt_news uses the l18n_parent field (one of the T3 oddities, there are actually 2 different parent fields). After changing the field it works correct!